# Cannot update record with ActiveRecord (no rails)

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Hello I have the following table in my PostgreSQL database:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_logins (token VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL, user_id UUID UNIQUE NOT NULL, create_date TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT clock_timestamp(), last_visit TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT clock_timestamp(), expire TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT clock_timestamp() + INTERVAL '30 DAYS');
```

For which I have the following ActiveRecord class

```rb
require "active_record"

class UserLogin < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

I want to update the `last_visit` column, which I try to do like this:

```rb
  def update_last_visited(user_token)
    user_login = UserLogin.find_by(token: user_token)

    if user_login == nil
      return false
    end

    user_login.update(last_visit: Time.now.utc)
  end
```

However, I get this error:

```
2023-02-19 11:55:21 - ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ...logins" SET "last_visit" = $1 WHERE "user_logins"."" IS NULL
```

As I have understood ActiveRecord if I have the object ActiveRecord should be able to update the record, or have I miss understood something?
Should I instead do an update based on a `where`?

A minimal reproducible example:

```rb
require "active_record"
require "yaml"
require 'securerandom'

db_config_file = File.open("database.yml")
db_config = YAML::load(db_config_file)
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(db_config)


class UserLogin < ActiveRecord::Base

end

def update_last_visited(user_token)
  user_login = UserLogin.find_by(token: user_token)
  
  if user_login == nil
    return false
  end
  
  user_login.update(last_visit: Time.now.utc)
end


user_login = UserLogin.new

user_login.token = "wompas"
user_login.user_id = SecureRandom.uuid

user_login.save

update_last_visited(user_login.token)
```

The `database.yml` file:

```
adapter: 'postgresql',
host: 'localhost',
port: 5432
username: 'user',
password: 'password',
database: 'dbname'
```

Note: The project does not utilise Rails, we only use ActiveRecord for its ORM capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UserLogin` doesn't have a primary key. But `ActiveRecord` expects tables to have a primary key column named `id` per default. See [Active Record Basics / Schema Conventions](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions) in the official Rails Guides.

In your example, it feels like the `user_id` can be used as a primary key, because is cannot be `NULL` and it must be unique. You can try to configure `user_id` to be used by as primary key by `ActiveRecord` like this.

```
class UserLogin < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :user_id
end
```

But in general, I suggest not fighting the default conventions and would just add a `bigint` `id` column to that table. While it is possible to configure custom primary key columns, it makes everything a bit more complex because you will need to remember those custom setting in other use cases – like, for example, when defining association.